# changing font-size and font-family for iFrame

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

How do I set the font-size and font-family for an iFrame (CSS or JQuery)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frames contain independent documents. Include a `<link>` element to your stylesheet in the documents you load in the frame.

Comment: I can't include that iFrame. I can only control iFrame after loaded.

Comment: Then dynamically add the link element using JavaScript. (Assuming that you really do mean that you can control it once it has loaded, since you can't control it before then I would have assumed that it is a third party document on a different host that you aren't allowed to touch for security reasons)